# What are the differences between coated drumheads and clear drumheads?

Tags: drums

What are the differences between clear drumheads and coated drumheads?

Do they have different purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some Key points about Coated Drumhead vs Clear Drumhead:

Coated Drum head:

- Coated heads are warmer in tone
- Easier to tune
- More controlled than Clear
- Produces more bounce when hit by the stick
- Muted and more focused

Clear Drum head:

- The tones are a bit higher in pitch
- Produce brighter and less controlled sound
- More attacks than coated
- Louder tone and more sustain

Clear heads are more recommended for the resonant side for toms and snare.  Coated heads are better for the batter side of the Snare.  For the Batter side of the toms,  it depends on the personal preferences of the drummer as well as for the type of music to be played.

These links have more discussions about drumhead.
http://silverlakestudio.com/2011/07/06/drumheadchoices/
http://www.moderndrummer.com/site/2011/10/what-you-need-to-know-about-drumheads/#.UZWTXKI3Bmw